# wp-admin: "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

Tags: wp-admin

After 2 weeks not using our WP site, logging into `/wp-admin/` gives a whitescreen error:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

I have:

- renamed `plugins` to `plugins.temp`.
- created a new admin user via phpMyAdmin. New user has `user_meta` role of `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}`.
- renamed `themes` to `themes.temp`.
- deleted core WordPress files, and replaced with newly uploaded files.
- replaced `.htaccess` with a default version.
- CHMOD all folders to 755 and all files to 644 recursively.
- turned on `WP_DEBUG` and found no errors.
- confirmed the `site_url` & `home_url` are set correctly in the options table of the db.

all without changing the error.

Help appreciated.

Edit:

- I've regenerated the security keys without anything changing.
- The site is singular, not multisite.
- The problem occurs after clearing cookies, and on all devices.
- The error occurs immediately after logging in and reaching `/wp-admin/`.
- I can get to `/wp-admin/index.php` but not `/wp-admin/` (original error)
- I can get to `/wp-admin/plugins.php` but not to `/wp-admin/update-core.php` (the first time, the same error), but the second time was okay.

Comment: Do you use the Limit Login Attempts plugin?  I remember having some issues with this not letting me log in, as someone had exceeded the number of login attempts attempting to break into my site.  Perhaps try disabling or resetting this plugin

Comment: Have you checked the DB? specifically the `wp_options` table, there are two rows that point to a url, it should be the same url as your domain

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, yes, they're set correctly.

Comment: @esotechnica, `plugins` has been renamed to `plugins.temp`

Comment: Can you add a new admin user via DB (there are a couple of guides how to do it) and use wp-admin with that user?

Comment: @Steve, are you using Multisite? Does the error happen right after you log in? Have you tried logging in from other pages (if you can) and going to other admin pages like the Plugins or Posts page? Do you remember anything suspicious that you or somebody (an admin on the site) may have done before the issue happened? Have you tried clearing your cookies, caches and/or using a different browser/device to access the site? Try regenerating the [security keys](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#security-keys)?

Comment: A further question to complement @Sally 's very pertinent comment. Does the problem occur when connecting to the network, to one of the generated sites, or both?

Comment: @SallyCJ, I've edited my question.

Comment: @FS-GSW, I've edited my question.

Comment: @Steve, I assume you are using a default Wordpress theme that has also been re-downloaded from the worpress repo. Do you have a backup of the DB from 2 weeks ago? Is this an online site?

Comment: @Steve, 1) Are you using any Must Use plugins (in `wp-content/mu-plugins`)? If yes, try renaming the folder. 2) I know you've already tried renaming the themes folder, but I'd still try switching to a default (and unmodified) theme like 2021 and see if the same issue persists. 3) Try installing WordPress (the default setup) in another directory or a subdomain in the same site, and see if logging in gives you the same error in question? 4) "turned on WP_DEBUG and found no errors" - maybe [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) would give you some insights?

Comment: Debug log or the PHP error log will give you/us a better idea of the issue. And if it's a managed host you'll probably have access to error log in the dashboard as well.

Comment: Have you checked your wp-config file for some unidentified code ?
Also some security plugins use `auto_prepend_file` to add security code which might not be removed just be renaming the plugin dir. Can you check if there's some php.ini or _user.ini file ?

Comment: Clear your browser cookies, or try in a new browser that has never accessed the admin

Comment: I agree with Sally, try turning off plugins as much as possible. I would also suggest taking a look at wp-config and switching to a default theme if none of that works.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have renamed the plugin and theme directory, it should a problem on your user. But rename the whole `wp-content` directory, so that all add-ons are inactive, check it again.

#### User Rights

After them, logged in to a database tool, like "Adminer" or "PhpMyAdmin" and look at the table `usermeta` with your **user ID***, like

> SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `user_id` = '1'`

Check the entries `wp_capabilities` and you should have the administrator key, like `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`.

***Note:** To identify your user ID, look at the frontend, list all your posts and look at the URL, the key `?author=` has your User ID. It is also possible after login in the wp-admin area on links with user keys.

#### Permalinks

Another chance to fix them is the `.htaccess` file. Maybe this is not correct, and you have issues with the permalinks.